# chat conversation messages has to come alternatively between buyer and supplier using codeigniter

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter

Chat between buyer(Testing as shown in image) and supplier (Maruthi as shown in image)code has shown below.Communication is also working properly but chat conversation messages has to come alternatively

**Customer value fetched from database**

```
<div class="smlpanel">

        <ul class="chat">
            <?php foreach ($customer_to_supplier as $row) { ?>  
                <li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
                        <?php $image = $row->profile_image; ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,' . $image; ?>" alt="User Avatar" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-circle" />
                  <!--<img src="<?php // echo 'data:image;base64,' .$image;     ?>" class="img-user" alt="" width="150px;" height="150px;"/>-->
                    </span>
                    <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                        <div class="header">
                            <strong class="primary-font"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted">
                                <?php $buyer_review = strtotime($row->msg_sent_time); ?>
                                <?php $date = date('d-F-Y', $buyer_review); ?>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span><?php echo $date; ?></small>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $row->message; ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
```

**supplier values fetched from database**

```
<?php foreach ($supplier_reply_to_customer as $row) { ?>
            <li class="right clearfix">  
                <span class="chat-img pull-right">
                    <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,' . $row->profile_image; ?>" alt="User oAvatar" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-circle" />
                </span>
                <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                    <div class="header">
                        <?php $buyer_review = strtotime($row->msg_sent_time); ?>
                        <?php $date = date('d-F-Y', $buyer_review); ?>
                        <small class=" text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span><?php echo $date; ?></small>
                        <strong class="pull-right primary-font"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></strong>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $row->message; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>

        <?php } ?>

    </ul>
```

**Inserting message form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_communication"> 
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="input-group">

            <input type ="hidden" name="suppid" id="suppid" value="<?php echo $row->supplier_id; ?>" class="form-control" />
            <input type ="hidden" name="proid" id="proid" value="<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>" class="form-control" />
            <input type ="hidden" name="custid" id="custid" value="<?php echo $row->Customer_id; ?>" class="form-control" />



            <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
 $id=$_GET['id'];
        $data['customer_to_supplier']=$this->Profile_model->customer_to_supply($id); 
        $this->load->view('messageview', $data);

        $data['supplier_reply_to_customer'] = $this->Profile_model->supplier_reply_to_customer($id); 
        $this->load->view('messageview', $data);
```

**Model**

```
public function customer_to_supply($id) {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('communication');
        $this->db->join('supplier_otherdetails', 'supplier_otherdetails.supplierid_fk = communication.supplier_id');
       $this->db->join('customer_otherdetails','communication.Customer_id=customer_otherdetails.customerid_fk');
        $this->db->join('customer_registration', 'communication.Customer_id=customer_registration.id');

        $array = array('communication.From' => 'customer', 'communication.product_id'=>$id,  'communication.supplier_id' =>  $this->session->id );
        $this->db->where($array);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $results = [];
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            $results = $query->result();
        }
        return $results;
    }


public function supplier_reply_to_customer($id) {




        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('communication');
        $this->db->join('supplier_otherdetails', 'supplier_otherdetails.supplierid_fk = communication.supplier_id');
        $this->db->join('supplier_registration', 'communication.supplier_id=supplier_registration.id');

//        $array = array('communication.From' => 'supplier', 'supplier_otherdetails.supplierid_fk' =>$this->session->id);
//        $where = "communication.From='supplier' and communication.id=communication.id";

        $array = array('communication.From' => 'supplier', 'communication.product_id'=>$id,'communication.supplier_id' =>$this->session->id);
        $this->db->where($array);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $results = [];
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            $results = $query->result();
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

[image: communication between testing and maruthi]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes in Customer value fetched from database**

```
                                    <?php
                                    if ($row->From == 'customer') {
                                        ?>
                                        <li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
                                                <?php $image = $row->profile_image; ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,' . $image; ?>" alt="User Avatar" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-circle" />
                                          <!--<img src="<?php // echo 'data:image;base64,' .$image;    ?>" class="img-user" alt="" width="150px;" height="150px;"/>-->
                                            </span>
                                            <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                                <div class="header">
                                                    <strong class="primary-font"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted">
                                                        <?php $buyer_review = strtotime($row->msg_sent_time); ?>
                                                        <?php $date = date('d-F-Y', $buyer_review); ?>
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span><?php echo $date; ?></small>
                                                </div>
                                                <p>
                                                    <?php echo $row->message; ?>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                    <?php } else { ?>


                                        <li class="right clearfix">  
                                            <span class="chat-img pull-right">
                                                <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,' . $row->profile_image; ?>" alt="User oAvatar" width="50px" height="50px" class="img-circle" />
                                            </span>
                                            <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                                <div class="header">
                                                    <?php $buyer_review = strtotime($row->msg_sent_time); ?>
                                                    <?php $date = date('d-F-Y', $buyer_review); ?>
                                                    <small class=" text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                                        <?php echo $date; ?>
                                                    </small>
                                                    <strong class="pull-right primary-font"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></strong>
                                                </div>
                                                <p class="pull-right">
                                                    <?php echo $row->message; ?>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                    <?php } ?>

                                </ul>
```

**Changes in model code**

public function customer_to_supply($id) {

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('communication');
    $this->db->join('supplier_otherdetails', 'supplier_otherdetails.supplierid_fk = communication.supplier_id');
   $this->db->join('customer_otherdetails','communication.Customer_id=customer_otherdetails.customerid_fk');
    $this->db->join('customer_registration', 'communication.Customer_id=customer_registration.id');

    $array = array('communication.product_id'=>$id,  'communication.supplier_id' =>  $this->session->id );
    $this->db->where($array);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $results = [];
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        $results = $query->result();
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**Changes in controller code**

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
        $data['customer_to_supplier']=$this->Profile_model->customer_to_supply($id); 
        $this->load->view('messageview', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would need two functions. Just pull all conversation related to that transaction and sort by time the communication was submitted.

You don't want to artificially alternate. What if the the buyer asks "Where's my item?" and doesn't get a response, so asks again? You want to show the conversation in the order it actually occurred.